# Laravel Passing Data into Blade giving Undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When trying to pass data into my blade file I am getting an undefined variable error

Controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    $data = semester::all();

    return view("AdminViews/adminSemester", ['semesters'=>$data]);
}
```

Blade:

```
 @foreach ($semesters as $semester)
            <tr>
                
                <td>{{ $semester->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $semester->code}}</td>
                <td>
```

It says $semesters is undefined even though i'm passing it correctly.

Also the route

```
Route::resource('semester', SemesterController::class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an extra route pointed at /semester, Removed it and ran php artisan route:clear. All fixed

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
return view("AdminViews/adminSemester", ['semesters'=>$data]);
```

Try this

```
return view("AdminViews/adminSemester", compact($data));
```

And in blade file:

```
 @foreach ($data $semester)
            <tr>
                
                <td>{{ $semester->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $semester->code}}</td>
```

Maybe it will helpful

Answer (score 1):

You forgot add your function index to the route.
Don't forget declare full path to your controller in web.php
(use App\Http\Controllers....)
Please try change your route to the:

```
Route::resource('semester', [SemesterController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Thanks you are kinda correct. I Didn't change my resource route but I had an extra get route pointed at the semester view and once I deleted that it fixed the error. Thanks your the reply

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this

```
 public function index()
{
    $data['semesters'] = semester::all();

    return view("AdminViews/adminSemester")->with($data);
}
```

in your blade `@foreach`

```
 @foreach ($semesters as $semester)
            <tr>
                
                <td>{{ $semester['name']}}</td>
                <td>{{ $semester['code']}}</td>
```